# How to check the value of a nested React component in a unit test with Enzyme and Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new in testing and I would like to access to a const

```
const Label = ({ intl, data }) => {
    if (data && data.length === 0) {
        return <div>{intl.translate('no_data')}</div>
    }
    return null
}
```

The test file:

```
test('should return null when is data', () => {
    const component = shallow(<StatisticsGraph {...mockPropsForComponent} />)
    const label = component.find(Label)
    expect(label).toEqual(null)
})
```

The variable `mockPropsForComponent` has the variable `data` with some values.
I want to know the value of `Label` for the test pass

Comment: @Icepickle — `Label` is a function. It will always be a function and never be null, no matter what it returns when it is called.

Comment: @Quentin how can I access to the return of the `Label` function?

Comment: By calling the function

Comment: @Quentin I don't know how to call it in enzyme...

Comment: The same way as you do anywhere else in JS. By putting `()` after the name. (Or using `call` or `apply` etc)

Comment: @Quentin not working....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different solutions, for different problems to solve.

## Testing an isolated component

Isolate the `Label` component in its own file and export it.

```
const Label = ({ intl, data }) => {
    if (data && data.length === 0) {
        return <div>{intl.translate('no_data')}</div>
    }
    return null
};

export default Label;
```

Then, test it individually. Like [Quentin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676815/know-the-value-of-a-const-variable-for-a-component-unit-test/57677524#comment101800729_57676815), a component is just a function you can call. We could call it directly, but it would leak irrelevant implementation details to the test. Instead, we assume it's a component and test it as such.

```
import Label from './Label';

describe('Label component', () => {
  it('returns null when there is data', () => {
    // works but leaks implementation details
    expect(Label({ data: ['anything'] })).toEqual(null);

    // Implementation agnostic test
    const wrapper = shallow(<Label />);
    expect(wrapper.isEmptyRender()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

## Testing a composition of components

Since you're testing `StatisticsGraph` and that your `Label` component has no identifiable selector, you could [use snapshots](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing) to make sure it's rendered correctly.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

describe('StatisticsGraph component', () => {
  it('renders properly', () => {
      const wrapper = render(<StatisticsGraph {...mockPropsForComponent} />);
      expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

> The **snapshot artifact should be committed** alongside code changes, and reviewed as part of your code review process. [...] On subsequent test runs Jest will simply compare the rendered output with the previous snapshot. If they match, the test will pass. If they don't match, either the test runner found a bug in your code that should be fixed, or the implementation has changed and the snapshot needs to be updated.

## Testing a component manually

If we really want to test each component's part manually, we may want to change the `Label` to be easier to find.

```
const Label = ({ intl, data }) => (
  <div className="label">
    {Boolean(data && data.length === 0) && intl.translate('no_data')}
  </div>
);
```

Then, the component should be found and we can use [`.isEmpty()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/isEmpty.html) to check that it worked.

```
describe('StatisticsGraph component', () => {
  it('does not render a label when there is data', () => {
      const component = shallow(<StatisticsGraph {...mockPropsForComponent} />);
      const label = component.find(Label);
      expect(label.isEmpty()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```